# Ни как не получается реализовать код

Tags: javascript

```js
function plus(){
    let y = +inp.value;
    
    if(result %2==0){
        result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
        result.style.color = "green";
    }else{
        result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
        result.style.color = "red"
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
         <h1 id="result">0</h1>
      <input id="inp">
     <button onclick="plus()">+</button> 
      
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: выводить чётные числа зелёным а нечётные красным цветами

Comment: Попробуйте словами описать что должен делать ваш код и что именно не получается. Мало кому интересно угадывать что же вам надо

Comment: Так у вас синтаксические ошибки. И тернарник не верный.

Comment: синтаксис вроде исправил но всё ровно не получается

Comment: @AlexeyTen, мало кому хочется помогать с исправлением кода, зная, что другим это не принесет никаких знаний.

Comment: @entithat, то есть? Хотите сказать мне ваш ответ не принесёт никаких знаний?

Comment: @Vahan ответ на Ваш вопрос не сможет помочь другим людям. А поможет только Вам. По-этому и никто и не стремится решать вопрос с мелкими правками. Мало кто будет искать подобный ответ в интернете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил пример с комментариями.

```js
    function plus(){
        let y = +inp.value;
        var result1 = +result.textContent + y; // Получаем результат складывания и делаем не канкатенацию, а сложение.

        if(result1 %2==0){ // проверка на чётность
            result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
            result.style.color = "green";
        }else{
            result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
            result.style.color = "red"; // добавляем ; к синтаксису
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="result">0</h1>
<input id="inp">
<button onclick="plus()">+</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, приведение к числу лишним не бывает ))) Но спасибо, подправил.

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема заключалась в том, что по `id` result вы получали не число и даже не число в строке, а элемент `<h1 id="result">0</h1>`;

```js
function plus() {
    const y = +inp.value;
    const val = +result.textContent + y;
    if(val % 2 === 0) {
        result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
        result.style.color = "green";
    }else{
        result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
        result.style.color = "red";
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="result">0</h1>
  <input id="inp">
  <button onclick="plus()">+</button>

</body>

</html>
```

P.S. В большинстве случаев `console.log()` ответит на ваш вопрос.